# iMac: Install/boot windows 8.1 on thunderbolt SSD, got 0xc000000e

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, ssd, boot-camp, imac

I was following http://bleeptobleep.blogspot.com/2013/02/mac-install-windows-7-or-8-on-external.html and successfully installed Windows 8.1 on a WD Element 2TB USB 3.0, without any issue.

However, since the performance was really poor to run Win8.1 on that WD Element, I purchased a [LaCie Little big Thunderbolt 512GB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009LJM6HQ) (256GB * 2 RAID), I formated the two Disk as simple NTFS format (i.e. RAID not enabled), and deployed Win8.1 installation and enabled bcdboot on the first disk, the processes were:

1. `imagex.exe /info C:\wim\install.wim`
2. `imagex.exe /apply C:\wim\install.wim 1 o:`
3. `o:\windows\system32\bcdboot o:\windows /f ALL /s b:`

So b: is the MBR primary section (500MB), and o: is a partition (60GB) on the thunderbolt disk 1 (256GB).

However, after rebooting from my iMac, while I tried to start the normal Win8.1 installation, I saw the Win8 BCD boot error: 0xc000000e, basically it prompts me that "**Your PC Needs to be Repaired**", displayed 9 options by pressing F8 key, I tried each one of them but no one even worked...

[image]

I really need help at this point, appreciate for any help!

Comment: `0xc000000e` means the Boot Manager(!) cannot access the Windows or boot partition. This indicates the BIOS emulation does not provide access to the hard disk. Whether that can be fixed, I don’t know.

Comment: @DanielB, thanks for the reply, I think you are right, but on iMac, should I follow this instruction to access the iMac "BIOS": http://www.ehow.com/how_6766567_open-imac-bios.html and then examine whether or not the LaCie disks are enabled for assecc?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Windows "slow" startup? This Apple Support [link](http://support.apple.com/en-us/TS4531) suggests it will resolve issues with Thunderbolt devices in Windows 8.

Now, how do you disable "fast" boot when Windows won't start? Try entering Safe Mode. If you can get this far, good indication that you are dealing with a driver issue.

Anyway, you'll need to access Windows Recovery Environment, more details can be found in [Windows Help](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-safe-mode). From here you should be able to access the Startup/Shutdown settings and uncheck the "Turn on fast startup".

Comment: I as I've discribed in my question, could't get into safe mode at all, I tried all the options and no one worked.  Still thanks for your reply though

Comment: No problem. Maybe a fresh install will help, rather than using an image. See [boot windows on a thunderbolt](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74977/is-it-possible-to-install-and-boot-windows-on-a-thunderbolt-drive). A bit tricky, requires a vm, but worth a shot. Good luck!